# Type superscript in figure captions?

Tags: captions

How can I have superscript in Figure captions ??

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth]{Chapters/CResults/figures/3AxisFlexure.png}
\caption{Thorlabs Microblock$^{TM}$ flexure 3-axis translation stage}
\label{fig:3AxisFlexure}
\end{figure}
```

I get errors but I want to know if my approach is right first.

Comment: The syntax is OK; however you can use `\texttrademark` as in `Thorlabs Microblocks\texttrademark`

Comment: yeah the duplicate page helped me ... Thanks @m0nhawk